# Selector array php to sting

Tags: php, arrays, variables, psql

This is output from print_r ($filename);

How can i select the [filename] so i can out put the two [filename] variables as one string?

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [filename] => 001-68316-000-9000-000.jpg
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [filename] => 001-68316-002-9000-001.jpg
        )

)
```

Comment: What do you mean by putting two file names as one string? Do you mean concatenating the strings like '001-68316-000-9000-000.jpg001-68316-002-9000-001.jpg'?

Comment: Possibly [array_column](https://www.php.net/array_column) is what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach ($filename as $item) {
 $file_name .= $item['filename']." ";
}

echo $file_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($filename as $item) {
   echo $item['filename'] . " ";
}
```

> 001-68316-000-9000-000.jpg 001-68316-002-9000-001.jpg